# Ruby - change value based on condition

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

How can I set the `hosts` value to be the IP address of the object if the default value is `target_vm`. If default value is `localhost` the the `hosts` value should be `localhost`.

I'm trying something like this..

```
hosts=> $evm.root['vm'].floating_ip_addresses if hosts == 'target_vm' else hosts,
```

Here is the function that I want to modify:

```
def run_async(env_vars, extra_vars, playbook_path, hosts: ["localhost"], credentials: [], verbosity: 0, become_enabled: false)
  run_via_cli(
    hosts => $evm.root['vm'].floating_ip_addresses || hosts,
    credentials,
    env_vars,
    extra_vars,
    :ansible_runner_method => "start",
    :playbook              => playbook_path,
    :verbosity             => verbosity,
    :become_enabled        => become_enabled
  )
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As i understand you want a one line if-else statement. If that so you can do it like this:

```
run_via_cli(hosts => hosts == 'target_vm' ? $evm.root['vm'].floating_ip_addresses : hosts)
```